# All profiles failing silently when submitted via Joomla frontend; in Administration they work fine

Tags: profile

I think this is a follow-on issue to my previous question still unsolved ([creation of new contact at user registration fails: The requested Profile is disabled OR it is not configured](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/creation-of-new-contact-at-user-registration-fails-the-requested-profile-is-dis/45978?noredirect=1#comment54365_45978)) but I think it qualifies as a different problem.

All the profiles in my CiviCRM instance work correctly and save data when called from the backend administration (Administer->Profiles->PROFILE_NAME->Settings->"Use in create/edit mode") but fail when called directly via the frontend website.

Using the direct URL (such as https://domain.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=16&reset=1) OR using the Administer->Profiles->PROFILE_NAME->more->"Use - create/edit mode" in the Admin backend, I get two types of behaviors:

1. Some profiles do not load at all; I am redirected to the site home page
2. Other profiles load and I am able to fill them out and submit them; I get a "Thank you, your information has been saved" with a summary of the entered data.  BUT that data is NOT saved or visible in the CiviCRM backend.

The most frustrating thing is that there are NO ERRORS.  I don't seem to be able to generate any backtraces or error messages in the Civi logs, PHP logs, Javascript consoles, or CMS debugging. And logging does seem to be working, I do have data showing up in the Civi and web site access logs, just no errors relating to the failed profile submissions.

Very grateful for any ideas how to proceed.

Joomla 3.10
CiviCRM 5.63.2

Comment: Ah, ONE profile does fail to load with the "Error The requested profile (gid=20) is inactive or does not exist." -- a new profile I created just for testing purposes.  But this error only appears in the frontend, I do not see it in the Civi logs.  And it definitely exists and is active.  Beyond frustrating.

Comment: I thought this must be a permissions issue, but these results are all happening with the Super User logged in both frontend and back.